# Bootstrap col-xs-12 larger than device width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
            <video autoplay muted>
                <source src="localVideoLink.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the video is larger than the screen and it does not automatically scale when the window is resized.

Comment: Remove the `row` class

Comment: Use a [responsive embed](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed) for the video

Comment: you have to add css to the video just putting it inside col-Xs-12 does not resize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using

> width: 100%;

for video tag in your styles.

Comment: I don't know who has done the downvote! But it is the correct answer and will work for any resolution.

Answer (score 1):

here the solution class: embed-responsive-item

```css
.row {
background: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" >
           <div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
                  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              </video>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `embed-responsive`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 embed-responsive" align="center">
      <video class="embed-responsive-item" autoplay muted>
                <source src="localVideoLink.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you given col-xs-12 it will work for the desktops resolution only if you want the video to be responsive you have to give for the devices resolutions for suppose

col-xs-12

col-lg-12

col-md-12

for every screen resolution there is some predefined sizes so use that

[Bootstrap col-*-*](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)